# In TinyMCE 4.0, how do I get the content of a textarea by id?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

In TinyMCE 3.x, I would use this code:

```
//TinyMCE 3.x
tinyMCE.get( "textAreaId" ).getContent();
```

But this is throwing an error in 4.x. How do I do this in 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

If given methods fail, you can always search for its value in the HTML document.

```
$('#textAreaId').siblings('.mce-tinymce.mce-container').find('.mce-container-body').find('.mce-edit-area').find('iframe').contents().find('#tinymce').find('p').html();
```

or

```
$('#textAreaId').siblings('.mce-tinymce.mce-container').find('.mce-container-body .mce-edit-area iframe').contents().find('#tinymce p').html();
```

a little more short

You can remove the final `.find('p')` if you want the content explicit with the tags.

The best one I think is:

```
window.parent.tinymce.get('textAreaId').getContent();
```

Pay attention, here is without the `#`